Whether the constant of a fractional Sobolev inequality is universal for all cubes
Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with $d\geqslant 1$ be a bounded open connected Lipschitz set, $\eta\in (0,1)$, $p>0$, and $\alpha>0$. Then the paper (On comparability of integral forms written by Bartlomiej Dyda, 2006) proves in (13) (the following \eqref{1}) that there exists a constant $C=C(d,p,\alpha,\eta,D)>0$, such that for any $u\colon D\to \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{equation}\label{1}\tag{*}
  \int_D\int_D\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
  \leqslant C\int_D\int_{B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D))}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
where $B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D))$ is the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D)$.
My question: if $D$ is a cube (a very special bounded Lipschitz domain), can the constant $C$ in \eqref{1} be independent of $D$ (that is, the constant $C$ is universal for all cubes)?

What happens if you do a coordinate transform that maps $D$ to $\lambda D$? I would expect that the same inequality holds for $\lambda D$ (but with $\eta$ replaced by $\lambda\eta$).

@daw But I think $\eta$ should not be replaced by $\lambda \eta$. Indeed, let $
\tilde{x}=\lambda x,\quad x\in D$, then
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{dist}(\tilde{x},\partial(\lambda D))=\lambda\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D).
\end{equation}
As a result, for every $y\in B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D))$,
\begin{equation}
|\tilde{y}-\tilde{x}|
=|\lambda y-\lambda x|
=\lambda |y-x|
<\lambda \eta \mathrm{dist}(x,\partial D)
=\eta \mathrm{dist}(\tilde{x},\partial(\lambda D)),
\end{equation}
hence $\tilde{y}\in B(\tilde{x},\eta\mathrm{dist}(\tilde{x},\partial(\lambda D))$.

Ok. This suggests that the constant is independent of $D$. Maybe you can write an answer yourself?

Any cube can be translated and scaled from the cube $Q(0,1)$, which is the cube centered at $0$ with edge length $1$. Therefore, to prove that the constant of (*) is universal for all cubes, we only need to prove that (*) is invariant under translation and scaling. Indeed, define the function
\begin{equation*}
  u\colon z+\lambda D\to \mathbb{R},
\end{equation*}
where $z+\lambda D=\{z+\lambda\hat{x}: \hat{x}\in D\}$. We want to show that
\begin{align}%\label{2}
  \int_{z+\lambda D}\int_{z+\lambda D}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x
  &\leqslant C\int_{z+\lambda D}\int_{B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial (z+\lambda D)))}
  \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x,\notag%\tag{**}
\end{align}
where the constant $C$ is the same in (*).
Now define
\begin{equation*}
  v(\hat{x})=u(z+\lambda \hat{x}),\quad \hat{x}\in D,
\end{equation*}
It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
  v\colon D\to\mathbb{R}. 
\end{equation*}
Define
\begin{align*}
  I
  &=\int_{z+\lambda D}\int_{z+\lambda D}\dfrac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
By letting $x=z+\lambda \hat{x}$ and $y=z+\lambda \hat{y}$, we find
\begin{align*}
  I
  &=\int_D\int_D\dfrac{|u(z+\lambda\hat{x})-u(z+\lambda \hat{y})|}{|(z+\lambda\hat{x})-(z+\lambda\hat{y})|^{d+\alpha}}
  \,\mathrm{d}(z+\lambda\hat{y})\mathrm{d}(z+\lambda\hat{x})\\
  &=\lambda^{2n-(d+\alpha)}\int_D\int_D \frac{|v(\hat{x})-v(\hat{y})|^p}{|\hat{x}-\hat{y}|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}\hat{y}\mathrm{d}\hat{x}
\end{align*}
Using (*) on $v$, we have
\begin{align}\label{2}
  I
  &\leqslant \lambda^{2n-(d+\alpha)}C\int_D\int_{B(\hat{x},\eta\mathrm{dist}(\hat{x},\partial D))} \frac{|v(\hat{x})-v(\hat{y})|^p}{|\hat{x}-\hat{y}|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}\hat{y}\mathrm{d}\hat{x}.\tag{**}
\end{align}
According to
\begin{equation*}
  \mathrm{dist}(x,\partial(z+\lambda D))=\lambda \mathrm{dist}(\hat{x},\partial D)
\end{equation*}
for $x=z+\lambda \hat{x}\in z+\lambda D$, we find that for every $\hat{y}\in B(\hat{x},\eta\mathrm{dist}(\hat{x},\partial D))$ with $y=z+\lambda\hat{y}$,
\begin{align*}
  |y-x|
  &=|(z+\lambda\hat{y})-(z+\lambda\hat{x})|\\
  &=\lambda |\hat{y}-\hat{x}|\\
  &<\lambda \eta\mathrm{dist}(\hat{x},\partial D)\\
  &=\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial(z+\lambda D)),
\end{align*}
which implies that $y\in B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial(z+\lambda D)))$. Hence by letting $\hat{x}=\frac{1}{\lambda}(x-z)$ and $\hat{y}=\frac{1}{\lambda}(y-z)$ in the right hand of \eqref{2}, we obtain
\begin{align*}
  I
  &\leqslant \lambda^{2n-(d+\alpha)}C\int_{z+\lambda D}\int_{B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial (z+\lambda D)))} \frac{|v(\frac{1}{\lambda}(x-z))-v(\frac{1}{\lambda}(y-z))|^p}{|(\frac{1}{\lambda}(x-z))-(\frac{1}{\lambda}(y-z))|^{d+\alpha}}
  \,\mathrm{d}\frac{1}{\lambda}(y-z)\mathrm{d}\frac{1}{\lambda}(x-z)\\
  &=C\int_{z+\lambda D}\int_{B(x,\eta\mathrm{dist}(x,\partial (z+\lambda D)))}
  \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x,
\end{align*}
which is the desired inequality.
